# Apple Mail prints tiny fonts after Maverick upgrade

Tags: mail.app, email, macos, printing, font

After installing Mavericks on my MacBook Pro 13 (non-Retina) and on my Mac Mini, a printed message from Mail appears in tiny font. This is independent of the printer (tried on Hp and on Epson). After much experimentation I found that I can only increase the printed font size by raising the viewed font size to 16 or above. Even when doing this the mail message header is still about size 8.

Does anyone know of a fix to this? Is there a setting in the printer's plist that can be changed?

This has been reported to Apple via Mail Feedback and Apple Care.

Comment: You may send Apple a Bug Report about this !

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem Mavericks since I installed the recent Mavericks Mail update on Nov 8/13 (I had no trouble before that). All I can do as of now is to copy the body of the email to Text Edit, type in the heading information and print from there.